# Microsoft.azure.devices.client version for .net core 1.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, iot, azure-iot-hub

I have a .Net 4.5.2 project that works with Azure IoT hub.  I'm trying to use the same code in a .Net core 1.1 (or Core 1.0) project but the package is not compatible.  Is there another package that provides the same device support?

Really comes down to DeviceClient type as in:

```
static DeviceClient deviceClient;
```

I could place the code in a 4.5.2 class library and try that.
Anyone have a full .net core device implementation?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/issues/31) is the issue you can vote up.

Answer (score 0):

We just published a new version of the device client SDK that is .Net Standard 1.3
You should now be able to use it in a .Net Core project.
Update the Nuget Package to latest version and try again.

Comment: A little more help if you don't mind, my webapi is .NetCoreApp1.1.  The WebApi references a class library project targeting .Net standard 1.6 with the device client SDK (1.2.9) referenced. Class Library compile fails to recognize the SDK.  Still trying to figure out all these core/standard/.net variations...

Comment: Interesting. The scenario you are describing should not be a problem. the library should be usable in a .Net Standard 1.6 library. Can you please share the output when the error occurs? Also which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Well, I guess operator error on my part.  I went back to my sets of DLL's and tried the class library set to .net core 1.1 with the SDK referenced and the build worked.  I then compiled the 1.1 webapi referencing that DLL and everything worked (head scratch).  So, I must have had something off or cached.  Thanks for the help and the new SDK version